# bash list postgresql databases over ssh connection

Tags: linux, bash, postgresql, ssh

I am doing some work on a remote Postgresql database.

When I log into the server this command works on bash:
**$  psql -c "\l"**

Remote login over ssh is possible using:

```
ssh user@server -C "cd /tmp && su postgres -c psql"
```

But why doesn't it work from this command?

```
ssh user@server -C " cd /tmp && su postgres -c psql -c '\l' "
→   bash: l: command not found
```

This is working, also "psql -l" but I don't understand why I have to use backslash 3 times here?

```
ssh user@server -C " cd /tmp && su postgres -c 'psql -c \\\l' "
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use several levels of quoting:

```
ssh user@server -C "cd /tmp && su postgres -c 'psql -c \"\\l\"'"
```

The double backslash is not strictly necessary since `\l` is no recognized escape sequence.

Comment: Thank you, this is working, but also without double slash \"\l\".  My main intention was to find out what the problem was: 1. why argument passed to bash 2. why is is working with 3 slashes